# how to link fields present in data extension to the profile attributes in all subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Hi have created a custom profile attribute and it's all working good when i am working with list.

importing a subscriber with the custom profile attribute field is populating the same field in all subscriber when I do a send to the list.

But when I create a data extension with the same field and import the data containing that field it populates the data extension but when doing a guided send email can be seen sent, and it is received by the subscriber.

the only thing is that the value for custom profile attribute is not populating for the subscriber and I am using that field for a subscriber filter in a business unit.

Comment: What is the sendable field in your Data Extension and does it match the subscriber in All Subscribers?

Comment: It's a standard DE with email address relates to subscribers on subscribers key.. and also does it makes a difference if it's a shared Data extension ??

Comment: I have created a fresh data extension with field matching the name of profile attribute i have created under parent account, imported fresh subscriber, sent an email.. subscriber gets added to all subscribers but the custom profile attribute field is not populating with the desired result and hence failing the subscriber filter i have created for a BU. Is it like the profile attributes will only work for a list not for a DE? or is there away to map profile attributes with DE fields?

Comment: Profile Attributes and Data Extensions are totally separate except for the mapping of the sendable field in the DE.    There's no automatic updating of those values either direction.  It's best to choose Lists or DEs instead of trying to use both.

Comment: Then how does first_name get uploaded automatically when all we use in our company is DE's along with a couple of other attributes. I am having the same issue.